# How to display an image from another machine in the same NAT on a .jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp, web-applications, routes

I have two applications:

1. for clients in which they send pictures than these pictures are stored on a disk
2. for admin in which he/she may see the picture and based on it approve or not some action requested by client.

Imagine 1st application that serves clients is running on 192.168.88.2 and 2nd is on 192.168.88.3. I want those pictures to be visible on .jsp page of a 2nd application. (I know absolute paths of those pictures) how can display them?

As for now both applications run on the same machine so for the sake of testing i store images in `src/main/webapp/images/` directory of my web appliction.

In `Dispatcher-servlet.xml`, i have the following lines of code:

`<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your application on server 1 publishes the images.
On server 2 you just include them using

```html
<img src="https://192.168.88.2/path/to/the/image/file.jpg"/>
```

Comment: I tried this way by using `<img src="https://127.0.0.1/C:/Users/vaio/workspace/image1.png" alt="Image1"/>` but it doesn't display an image.

Comment: Also doesn't `https://` mean that application sends `https` request to `127.0.0.1`, so I need to handle it somehow?

Comment: @TeamBeam As I understood you are running an web application on server 1. So I thought you are able to publish the images through http(s) on server 1 so you can access them on server 2.